# ASP.NET MVC 5 ayuda con JWT al logear

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, api, jwt

estoy desarrollando una aplicación web la cual consume la data desde una `API`, esta al momento de logearme me devuelve un `token`. Ese token debe ser usado en las demás consultas internas de la aplicación ya que se debe enviar en cada `request` en el `header` del `post`.

Es acá donde no se como poder manejar esa respuesta, si se debe almacenar en una variable de `session["authToken"]`, en una cookie o bien transportar el `token` en alguna variable `const` o `static` para poder usarla dentro del ciclo de vida de cada usuario.

Ya que para el primer `request (solicitud login)` se debe enviar sin el encabezado `authorization` pero en los demás `request` una vez logeado, debería agregar en la linea `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(post);` de mi clase `HttpService` el `token` para hacer las demás consultas.

Sería genial si alguien supiera una buena forma de lograr esto y que me pueda ayudar. 
A continuación explayo mi código. Gracias.

Mi controlador:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(Login model)
{
    object Token = await PostLoginAsync(model, "api/login");

    return View();
}
```

Método que retorna el `token`:

```
public static async Task<Object> PostLoginAsync(Login model, string path)
{
    RootObject RootObject = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpService.GenerateClient().PostAsJsonAsync(path, model);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        RootObject = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>();
    }

    return RootObject;
}
```

Mi clase `HttpService`:

```
public static HttpClient GenerateClient()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:0000/");
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(post);

    return client;
}
```

Comment: Te dejo este artículo de recomendada lectura [JSON Web Token - Seguridad en servicios Web API 2 de ASP.NET](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/6/17/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-2-de-aspnet)

Answer (score 0):

Si tu sitio no es una [Single Page App](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) no es una buena idea que manejes la sesión con JWT porque vas a tener muchos inconvenientes principalmente al momento de hacer peticiones GET en la página. Lo mejor es que cambies el método de autenticación.

Si es una Single Page App que usa MVC desarrollada por ejemplo con AngularJS o Backbone, lo mejor que puedes hacer es **almacenar el token en el local storage y realizar la redirección con Javascript**.

Acá hay unas ideas de como hacerlo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545875/how-to-store-authentication-bearer-token-in-browser-cookie-using-angularjs